# How to know which element matched in java-8 anymatch?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Assuming I have an enum

```
enum Country {
    China, 
    USA, 
    Others
}
```

Say I have a 
`list1 = ["China", "Shanghai", "Beijing"]` and a check for `isChina`, if true, then return Country.China.

`list2 = ["USA", "Dallas", "Seattle"]` and a method checks for `isUSA`, if true then return Country.USA.

If USA or China is missing from the list, then return Country.Others.

Assumption: A list will always contain only 1 country followed by cities in that country.

[Edit] Do not assume, country would be first element in the array.

While I find it extremely easy to implement in Java-7, I am not sure of the most elegant way to do this using streams

```
for (String str: list) {
   if (str.equals("China")) {
       return Country.China  
   } 
   if (str.equals("USA")) {
       return Country.USA; 
   }
}
return Country.Other;
```

I am looking for a clean implementation using Streams.

Comment: If the list will always contain only 1 country followed by cities in that country, then country will always be the first element in the list, so why search the list at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `filter` operation for the conditions and `findFirst` to get the first match, then transform to the respective `Country.China` or `Country.USA` otherwise return `Country.Others` if there was not match.

```
 return list.stream()
            .filter(str -> "China".equals(str) || "USA".equals(str))
            .findFirst()
            .map(s -> "China".equals(s) ? Country.China : Country.USA)
            .orElse(Country.Others);
```

Alternatively:

```
return Stream.of(Country.values()) // or Arrays.stream(Country.values())
             .filter(o -> list.contains(o.toString()))
             .findFirst().orElse(Country.Others);
```

The first solution will always check for "China" before checking for "USA" which is the exact equivalent of your imperative approach, However, the latter doesn't always respect that order, rather it depends on the order of the enum constants declarations in `Country`.

Comment: The equivalent of [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) would be [`findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--), not [`findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--).

Comment: @Andreas according to the  _illustrated_ code, it's behaving as `findFirst`, not `findAny`

Comment: It is smooth :/

Comment: Well, the illustrating code is a loop and it’s impossible to write a loop that demonstrates that the author doesn’t care about the order (just like `anyMatch` on a sequential stream still returns the first match in most cases). So @Andreas’ comment about the OP referring to `anyMatch` is right. The fact that the predicate in your first variant checks for `"China"` first, is entirely irrelevant, as a string can never match both anyway. Swapping the order would not change the outcome. You could also write `.filter(str -> str.matches("China|USA"))` or `.filter(Set.of("China", "USA")::contains)`.

Answer (score 3):

If the string matches the enum token then it's pretty simple:

```
return Arrays.stream(Country.values())
    .filter(c -> c.name().equals(list.get(0))
    .findAny().orElse(Country.Others);
```

This is assuming the first element of the list is the name as you specified.

Comment: I doubt this would work. Compare it with the basic iterative approach for example.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution using the ternary operators would be :

```
Country searchCountry(List<String> list) {
    return list.contains("China") ? Country.China : 
            list.contains("USA") ? Country.USA : Country.Others;
}
```

Comment: Though the worst-case time-complexity here also remains `O(n)`, just that it's precisely twice that of n. (`2n`) which is when "China" is not on the list and "USA" is also searched for.

Answer (score 1):

```
Country findCountry(List<String> countries) {
  return Arrays.stream(Country.values())
    .filter(country -> countries.contains(country.name()))
    .findAny()
    .orElse(Country.Others);
}
```

Comment: The equivalent of [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) would be [`findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--), not [`findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--).

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the Country is always followed by cities in said country, which means that the first element must be the country. From that we can define an easy helper method inside the enum, and we're done:

```
public static Country valueOf(String value){
    for(Country country : values()){
        if(country.name().equals(value)){
            return country;
        }
    }
    return Country.Others;
}
```

you then can just call that mehtod with:

```
Country country = Country.valueOf(list1.get(0));
```

No need to use Java8.

Answer (score 1):

If this assumption holds:

> A list will always contain only 1 country followed by cities in that country.

Then, it would be enough to compare the first element of the list and return the enum element that matches, otherwise fallback to `Country.Others`.

So, according to the problem statement, there's no need to iterate the list, hence no need to use streams at all.

Your Java 7 code is not the best either, because it iterates the list. If you want a one-liner, the ternary operator would do it:

```
return "China".equals(list.get(0)) ? Country.China :
       "USA".equals(list.get(0))   ? Country.USA   :
                                     Contry.Others;
```

I would even factor out `list.get(0)`:

```
String first = list.get(0);
return "China".equals(first) ? Country.China :
       "USA".equals(first)   ? Country.USA   :
                               Contry.Others;
```